# How to access all the columns of a matrix one by one for normalizing in R

Tags: r, normalization, matrix

I have a matrix which looks like this:

```
Col1| Col2| Col3 | Col4 | Col4 | ....
    |     |      |      |      | ....
    |     |      |      |      | ....
```

and I want to normalize the values column by column in the range [0,1]. I know the formula to normalize which is:

```
normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

where x is a vector or values to be normalized. How do I do this process for each column of the matrix one at a time without having to specify the columns names and do it manually for each each column in R.Also I want to insert back the normalized values thereby replecing earlier values in the same old matrix or form a new matrix. I mean I want something like:

```
for(each column of matrix mat)
{
//do the normalization of values for that column
//insert back normalized values at the same location in the old matrix or form a new matrix and insert there 
}
```

I am new to R and as such do not have much of knowledge about complex calculations in R.Any help will be great for me.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply()` function

```
apply(youdataframe, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function (x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scale` function which will subtract a constant from each column, then divide each column by a constant.  The default is to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation, but if instead you pass the minimum value as the `center` and the difference between the maximum and minimum as the `scale` then it will normalize to the [0,1] range by column:

```
newmat <- scale( oldmat, center=apply(oldmat, 2, min), 
     scale = apply(oldmat, 2, max) - apply(oldmat, 2, min) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is in the vegan package (part of function `decostand()`) which illustrates some extra steps one might wish to take in robustifying such a function. It also illustrates the fast(-ish) `sweep()` function which often gets overlooked in favour of `apply()` in such circumstances.

```
norm <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if (wasDF <- is.data.frame(x)) {
    x <- as.matrix(x)
  }
  mins <- apply(x, 2, min, na.rm = na.rm)
  maxs <- apply(x, 2, max, na.rm = na.rm)
  ran <- maxs - mins
  ran <- pmax(.Machine$double.eps, ran, na.rm = na.rm)
  x <- sweep(x, 2, mins, "-")
  x <- sweep(x, 2, ran, "/")
  if (wasDF) {
    as.data.frame(x)
  }
  x
}
```

In use this gives:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)
nmat <- norm(mat)

> apply(nmat, 2, range)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

Another, simple, alternative is to use the existing `scale()` function and supply the required values to arguments `center` and `scale` rather than using the defaults (which would standardise the data):

```
mins <- apply(mat, 2, min)
maxs <- apply(mat, 2, max)
nmat2 <- scale(mat, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)

> apply(nmat2, 2, range)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```